# Ansible to have different group name for same ip address in inventory

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

In Ansible host inventory, my file is a below.

```
[all:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_user="{{ username }}"
ansible_ssh_pass="{{ password }}"

[server_1]
125.23.49.13

[server_2]
125.23.49.13

[server_3]
145.33.39.43
```

How can i combine like if server_1 or server_2 to use the ip address of 125.23.49.13 as i need this design as i will be passing the value from jenkins for the host name and group variable location. However, group variable have different location different values but host ip address have same value.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have same host in multiple groups and have your variables with different values at different locations, ansible with do a "merge" before executing the play.

> If a host is a member of multiple groups, Ansible reads variable values from all of those groups. If you assign different values to the same variable in different groups, Ansible chooses which value to use based on internal rules for merging

Reference : https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html

Now, during merge, below is the official doc :

> By default variables are merged/flattened to the specific host before a play is run
>
> By default, Ansible overwrites variables including the ones defined for a group and/or host (see DEFAULT_HASH_BEHAVIOUR). The order/precedence is (from lowest to highest):

- all group (because it is the ‘parent’ of all other groups)
- parent group
- child group
- host

> By default Ansible merges groups at the same parent/child level alphabetically, and the last group loaded overwrites the previous groups

Reference : https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#how-we-merge

So, it will depend on location(s) where variables are defined and how they are merged.

Comment: Although it says "alphabetically," I believe technically is in ASCII order.  Alphbetically, `groupB` would override `groupa`.  It does not.  But `groupB` does override `groupa`.